# How do I write the query for this table for the following resulting table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I am not the most experienced SQL user, and I was tasked with writing a SQL procedure, and I just would like some help in writing a SQL query that will help in returning the following resulting table.

The original tables, I will call them here, S and A.

S looks like the following below, which are the columns:

"SetID, Name, OwnerID, Tag, ExpirationDate, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn"

A looks like the following below, which are the columns:

"AFID, AFSetID, TypeId, AFGroupID, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn"

Write now my query looks like the following below. Don't mind the complicated Join statements and the Where Clause, they are correct, and there is nothing wrong there since that was old code.

I need help I believe in my SELECT statement, and the Group By Clause is definitely wrong.

```
        SELECT s.AFSetID, s.Tag, s.Name, s.ModifiedOn, a.AFGroupID, a.AFID
        FROM  dbo.TAvoidFavorSet s with (nolock, forceseek)
        INNER JOIN @owners o ON o.OwnerId = s.OwnerID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TAvoidFavor a WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.AFSetID = s.AFSetID AND ((@primaryOnly = 1 AND (a.GridLevel = 0 OR a.PrimaryAFID IS NULL)) OR (@primaryOnly = 0))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup_AvoidFavorType t ON t.TypeID = a.TypeID   
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TAvoidFavorPLID p WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.AFID = a.AFID
        WHERE s.AFSetID = COALESCE(@afSetID, s.AFSetID)
        GROUP BY s.AFSetID, a.AFGroupID, s.ModifiedOn, s.Tag, s.Name, a.AFID
```

And the returned table looks something like this.

```
AFSetID, Tag, Name, ModifiedOn, AFGroupID, AFID
1         x    A     blahblah     100       5
1         x    A     blahblah     200       15
1         x    A     blahblah     300       25
1         x    A     blahblah     400       35
1         x    A     blahblah     500       45
2         y    B     blahblah     150       16
2         y    B     blahblah     250       24
2         y    B     blahblah     250       543
2         y    B     blahblah     450       234
3         z    C     blahblah     425       23
3         z    C     blahblah     425       66
3         z    C     blahblah     322       97
```

I want a resulting table that looks something like the following below. I want to group them by the AFsetID, and the count of the distinct AFGroupID per AFsetID should be in the AFDistinctGroupCount column. And AFIDCount holds a non-distinct count of AFID per AFsetID.

```
AFSetID, Tag, Name, ModifiedOn, AFDistinctGroupCount, AFIDCount
1         x    A     blah blah          5                 5
2         y    B     blah blah          3                 4
3         z    C     blahblah          2                 3
```

Anybody who wants to help I would appreciate it alot. I don't believe it is just adding some COUNT operation in the select statement cause I tried various angles of that. I think this requires a double select query, and that has me lost.

Thanks

Comment: [Stop splattering nolock in your code](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - especially if you don't fully understand the consequences and have a good reason for using it.

Comment: Its old code I am copying and slightly changing. I am not touching that part. That part was written by a database expert. It should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a COUNT(distinct a.AFGroupID) and COUNT(a.AFID) would make it work. See code below:

```
SELECT s.AFSetID, s.Tag, s.Name, s.ModifiedOn, 
COUNT(distint a.AFGroupID), COUNT(a.AFID)
    FROM  dbo.TAvoidFavorSet s with (nolock, forceseek)
    INNER JOIN @owners o ON o.OwnerId = s.OwnerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TAvoidFavor a WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.AFSetID = s.AFSetID AND ((@primaryOnly = 1 AND (a.GridLevel = 0 OR a.PrimaryAFID IS NULL)) OR (@primaryOnly = 0))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup_AvoidFavorType t ON t.TypeID = a.TypeID   
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TAvoidFavorPLID p WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.AFID = a.AFID
    WHERE s.AFSetID = COALESCE(@afSetID, s.AFSetID)
    GROUP BY s.AFSetID, s.ModifiedOn, s.Tag, s.Name
```

Since you want to count the AFID and AFGroupID, you do not want to group on them.

Comment: No that doesn't work that returns a table that isn't grouped by the AFSetID. It lists every AFSetID one by one. And I have over 1000 entries of which there are only four unique AFSetID. The query you suggested and I tried it before as well returns 1000 rows. I want it to return 4 rows

Comment: Yes, sorry. I removed the grouping on them, I did not see them at first. The code is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove `a.AFGroupID` and `a.AFID` from the GROUP BY clause and aggregate on them:

```
SELECT s.AFSetID, s.Tag, s.Name, s.ModifiedOn, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.AFGroupID) AFDistinctGroupCount, 
       COUNT(a.AFID) AFIDCount
FROM  dbo.TAvoidFavorSet s with (nolock, forceseek)
INNER JOIN @owners o ON o.OwnerId = s.OwnerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAvoidFavor a WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.AFSetID = s.AFSetID AND ((@primaryOnly = 1 AND (a.GridLevel = 0 OR a.PrimaryAFID IS NULL)) OR (@primaryOnly = 0))
LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup_AvoidFavorType t ON t.TypeID = a.TypeID   
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TAvoidFavorPLID p WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.AFID = a.AFID
WHERE s.AFSetID = COALESCE(@afSetID, s.AFSetID)
GROUP BY s.AFSetID, s.ModifiedOn, s.Tag, s.Name
```